# Send ararylist from js to spring controller

Tags: javascript, java

I want to send an `arrayList` from `javaScript` to `spring controller`, I have written this code but it doesn't work, when I call this `function` nothing happens.

```
function order_(){
     var itemOrder = $('#sortable').sortable("toArray");
      $.ajax({
        contentType:"application/json;",
        type : "POST",
        url : "/my_url",
        data : (itemOrder), 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { alert("Mapping Successful") },
        failure: function (data) { alert("not working..."); }
        });
  }
```

My `spring controller`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my_url", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                 consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public @ResponseBody String getItemOrder(@RequestBody String[] itemOrder) {       
       // code to get itemOrder }
```

Is there something wrong in this code?

Comment: What does the variable `itemOrder` contain? Also, `dataType` should be 'json` rather than `jSon`. Also, depending on how you are using Spring, rather than accepting a `String[]` into your `Submit` method, the data can be auto-marshalled into a type (model/entity). It is much more useful this way. Otherwise you have to write a mapper yourself.

Comment: thanks for your answer, firstly yes I know jSon should be json, but the editor of this site don't allow me to write 'json', secondly I don't want to do any data binding, just I want to get the value of arrayList itemOrder to do some processes, what I need exactly is when I call the js function order_() , automatically it call the spring method getItemOrder() and send the value of arrayList itemOrder to it ;

Comment: The code you have does that. Please remove the `()` from around `itemOrder` on the `data` property.

Comment: if this code is not working, then please identify what doesn't work, error conditions, what error messages are shown in the console, etc.

Comment: You need to tell us what is in `itemOrder` in order for us to help you.

Comment: I dont know what exactly what not is not working, but what I m sure about, is order_() function is called, and the console show me 0 errors.
the content of itemOrder : var itemOrder = $('#sortable').sortable("toArray"); // array of sortable elements